How to fit axis and radius of 3D cylinder？
Once I get some 3-D point coordinates, what algorithm do I use to fit an optimal cylindrical and get the direction vector and radius of the central axis？

My previous idea was to divide a cylinder into layers, and as the number of layers increased, the figure formed by the dots got closer to the cylinder, but in this case I couldn't get an exact radius of the cylinder. (The central axis is obtained by fitting the center of the circle through each layer)

Welcome to SO, could you provide the dataset as a link (no screenshot).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your exhibit presents an optical illusion.

Here is a MCVE to regress axis defined by p0 and p1 (vectors) and radius R (scalar).
First we create some dummy dataset:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

def cylinder(n=60, m=20, r=2, h=5):
    t = np.linspace(0, m * 2 * np.pi, m * n)
    z = np.linspace(0, h, m * n)
    x = r * np.cos(t)
    y = r * np.sin(t)
    return np.stack([x, y, z]).T

X = cylinder()
rot = Rotation.from_rotvec(np.array([-1, 2, 0.5]))
x0 = np.array([1., 2., 0.])
    
X = rot.apply(X)
X = X + x0

Which create a generic use case including origin shift.
Now it is sufficient to write down the geometric equation (see equation 10) as residuals and minimize it by least squares.
def residuals(p, xyz):
    return np.power(np.linalg.norm(np.cross((xyz - p[0:3]), (xyz - p[3:6])), axis=1) / np.linalg.norm((p[3:6] - p[0:3])), 2) - p[6] ** 2

p, res = optimize.leastsq(residuals, x0=[0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.], args=(X,), full_output=False)

Which in this case returns:
# array([ -1.8283916 ,  -1.65918186,   3.29901757,  # p0
#         20.31455462,  26.98786514, -22.52837088,  # p1
#          2.        ])                             # R

Graphically it leads to:


What is the reason to use distance^2 - radius^2 instead of (distance - radius)^2? I've tried the latter and it also worked but I would like to understand your version
